# How to move local GitHub Visual Studio Projects to BitBucket

Tags: github, bitbucket

I recently lost my phone which had Google Authenticate installed and I used to access my GitHub account. Meaning I am no longer able to log into GitHub.

I have emailed GitHub and they informed me that I didn't have a "fallback" authentication method setup and can no longer log in.

I have about 30 Visual Studio projects that I want to move to my account on BitBucket. They are on my "D" drive as well as in GitHub.

I would prefer to keep all the code changes since the projects were created if possible?

Can anyone explain the best way to reconfigure VS and move the projects to BitBucket please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your local drive, it should be a simple matter of:

- create an empty BitBucket repository ([as shown here](https://zapier.com/apps/bitbucket/tutorials/how-to-push-to-bitbucket))
- renaming the remote origin to a BitBucket URL
- pushing everthing

That is:

```
cd D:\path\to\one\project
git remote set-url origin https://bitbucket.org/<you>/yourProject.git
git push --all
```

Make sure you have `git config credential.helper` set to manager: that will cache your credentials (BitBucket username/password)

Visual Studio will pick up the new URL automatically, since said URL is associated with the default remote "`origin`".

The [OP Trevor Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153795/trevor-daniel) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625777/how-to-move-local-github-visual-studio-projects-to-bitbucket/58631727#comment103581459_58631727):

> The only thing extra thing I did was to, in VS, change the "`Remotes`" URL to match the Bitbucket URL in `Team Explorer > Home > Settings > Repository Setting`.

Comment: The only thing extra thing I did was to, in VS, change the "Remotes" url to match the bitbucket url in Team Explorer > Home > Settings > Repository Settings

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.